# Back button to go to previous page

Tags: java, android, button

I am trying to create a back button to return to the previous screen. I have a next button which moves from the current screen (screen2) to the next screen (screen4) however I want a back button to do the reverse process .. i.e to return to screen 2. I have called the button and named the id. I was wondering could anyone tell me why the code below isn't working.. The code is as follows:

```
Button backbutton;

        backbutton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.back_button);       
        backbutton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                setContentView(R.layout.screen2);

            }
        });
```

`

Comment: your question is unclear explain more about it

Comment: can you please add the problem you are trying to solve ?

Comment: so, it does what it should do? nice. good work. don't understand the need to create a question for it, though

Answer (score 3):

If you are trying to make this button act the same as the regular back button on the Android device itself you can make use of the onBackPressed() method

So your code would be something like this:

```
backbutton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.back_button);       
backbutton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        onBackPressed(); //OPTION 1: If in an activity
        getActivity().onBackPressed();  //OPTION 2: If in a fragment
    }
});
```

Choose whichever line of code suits your needs depending on where you are, in activity vs in fragment.

Answer (score 0):

Just finish activity

```
backbutton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.back_button);       
backbutton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        finish();

    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can simple call the `onBackPressed()` system method inside your `onClickListener` interface.

something like this:

```
backbutton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        onBackPressed();
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Call this method `onBackPressed();` when you are click button.

```
 backbutton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.back_button);       
    backbutton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
       onBackPressed();

       }
    });`
```

Comment: This is wrong he wants to do back press functionality not open a new Activity

Comment: do you want to system back button to stop or go previous

Comment: While this code snippet may be the solution, [including an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-‌​code-based-answers) really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion.